# Move top-linkss after search-bar

Tags: magento2, topmenu

I am trying to move `top menu` after the `search bar` but its moving into wrapper section.
Code used:

```
<move element="top.links" destination="header-wrapper" />
```

Comment: Can you please provide any screenshot

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
      <move element="catalog.topnav" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo"/>
    </body>
</page>

Comment: can you check it where is my mistake

Comment: <move element="top.links" destination="header-wrapper" />

Comment: add your code in question, or elaborate sharing screenshots

Comment: Which theme are you used?

Comment: <move element="navigation.sections" destination="header.panel"/>

Comment: This will be help ful

Comment: @are you want move  `top  links`(like  sign in,  Create an Account) to after the search box ?

Comment: yes sir i want it after the search box

Comment: <move element="navigation.sections" destination="header.panel"/>

Comment: this is not helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
    <move element="top.links" destination="header-wrapper" after="top.search"/>
```

Reference:

[image]

Comment: give right detail this is not work

Comment: check your browser console, its moved after the search bar, you need to alter via css.

Comment: it not work can givse me complete detail

Comment: @ i update  screen shot check it.

Comment: not working for me

Comment: @ are you using custom theme?  then post you full code and file paths

Comment: @ are you fixed that issue

Comment: No Its not Working For me

Comment: @Rajkumar.E My script : <move element="header.links" destination="header-wrapper" after="top.search" />  still header links show near logo, how to update?

Comment: I have moved customer links to header wrapper using : <move element="header.links" destination="header-wrapper" after="minicart" />  How placed after minicart?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please find the below screenshot

[image]

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.menu" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Menu</argument>
    </arguments>
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>
</block>
```

> /vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

Use the above code after the logo section, for reference use the screenshot.

and you will need to adjust your header design.

You can call your code in your theme

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Monu if this answer is useful vote this it will be useful to others thanks